# Clojure compile issue

Tags: clojure

Why the following code cann't pass compilation?

```
(defn testit [asym] (var asym))
```

The error is:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: asym in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asym` there is not a `var`, it's a local; in this case, the sole argument to the function that you're defining as the value of the `testit` var.

If you want to return `asym` from that function:

```
(defn testit [asym] asym)
```

If `asym` is a symbol that names a var you want to return, then use `resolve`:

```
(defn testit [asym] (resolve asym))
```

General note: `(var x)` is the expanded [special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#var) corresponding to the reader syntax `#'x`.